# How can I make scanf() with multiple inputs ignore the others?

Tags: c, input, formatting, stdin, scanf

```
scanf("%s %d %s %d",word1,&num1,word2,&num2);
```

so when the user inputs "quit", its supposed to stop asking for the other 3 inputs. however it asks me to input another "quit" probably because there are 2 %s in the format

is there anyway around this? 
EDIT: because it has to get 4 inputs in a loop, unless a quit is inputted.

Comment: You could have a more fancy input parsing. Maybe you could use `flex` + `bison`, or `antlr` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch One can understand why you suggest writing a complete LALR parser for a 4-word user input only when one sees your profile and finds out you're a core GCC hacker :P

Comment: It was not said that there are only 4 different words....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` is a very blunt tool that is not good at talking to unstructured inputs (including humans :-) ).  In general, if you are interacting with a person, you should start with `fgets` to read a line, then pick the resulting line apart however is most convenient, possibly including `sscanf`.

It's worse than you think because the `%d` directive will jam up if you feed it something that is not scan-able as an integer.  For instance, if you enter `quit now`, the first `%s` directive will read the word `quit` but the `%d` will leave `now` in the input stream, causing `scanf` to return 1 (one successful conversion-and-assignment).  The next attempt to read a string will obtain and consume the `now`; to naive code, this will seem like it was a later, second input line, rather than a continuation of the first one.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `scanf()` doesn't work how we think it does. Perhaps you could suggest an alternative, `fgets()`, for example.

Comment: @H2CO3: the second line suggests starting with `fgets`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

scanf("%s ", word1);
if (strcmp(word1, "quit") != 0)
    scanf("%d %s %d", &num1, word2, &num2);
```